# `du` and `awk` commands not found when running a script

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I was going through a tutorial on the latest Linux Shell Handbook for Linux Pro mag and I am having trouble getting this block of code to work.  When I run the script it tells me that `du` and `awk` commands are not found.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/user/bin
. /usr/local/sbin/functions.bash

printf "USER\tGB USED\n"
for WHO in $(</user/local/sbin/chusers); do
    HOMESUM=`eval du -s -$WHO |awk '{print $1}'`
    TMPLIST=$( ls -lR --block-size 1024 $(</user/local/bin/chdirs) | egrep "^.......... +[0-9]+ $WHO" | awk '{print $5}' )
    TSUM=0
    for N in $TMPLIST; do
        TSUM=$(( $TSUM+$N ))
    done
    TOT=$(( $HOMESUM+$TSUM ))
    to_gb $WHO $TOT
done
```

Here is the `to_gb` function from `function.bash`

```
to_gb()
    {
        local MB D1 D2 USER
        USER=$1
        MB=$(( $2/1024))
        D1=$(( $MB/1000))
        D2=$(( $MB-($D1*1000) ))
        printf "%s\t%s\n" $USER $D1.${D2:0:1}
        return
    }
```

I have been able to run each command `du -s ~username` and `awk '{ print $1 }'` from the command line with no problem and seen the expected output but the script fails to work.

Comment: also chusers and chdirs is a flat file containing usernames and directories to check.

Comment: The `to_gb()` function seems rather limited. I like to use [this function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/a-standard-tool-to-convert-a-byte-count-into-human-kib-mib-etc-like-du-ls1/259254#259254) that converts the file size to Bytes, KiB, MiB, GiB, TiB, EiB, PiB, YiB and ZiB.

Comment: I see some really horrible stuff in Linux magazines tbh. Better you reformulate your question by writing a description of specifically what you want to do, and what help you need with that, otherwise we are all going to pick holes in the script in the comments, without really knowing what the desired output is, instead of giving you a useful answer (although [Florian Diesch's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/943644/527764) should solve the painfully obvious issue causing the command not found errors...)

Answer (score 1):

```
PATH=/bin:/user/bin
```

should be

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
```

Both `awk` and `du` are in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ type -p du;type -p awk
/usr/bin/du
/usr/bin/awk
```